# How to get a correlation between two variables using LASSO model and then build a regression model between the variables in MATLAB R2014b

Tags: matlab, regression, prediction

I have to variables X as independence and Y as dependence. I want to get a regression between X and Y using LASSO model and then build a regression model and predict Y from X with LASSO model. For example

X=randi([1,5],30,1);

Y=randi([1,10],30,1);

Comment: nice! And have you tried anything to get this?

Comment: No, I previously used glm package to run this model in R programming and get results but I don't know how I can use it in matlab.

Comment: Unfortunately this is too close to a code request, which is no allowed in stackoveflow. We help you with your code, but I see no code to help you with.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have any code to share here to simplify my question.